# How to group on a Bag

Tags: apache-pig

I tried the following -

```
C = FOREACH A GENERATE dataMap#'$key_name' AS C_ID, dataMap#'$key_name2' AS methodName, pool,time;
D = GROUP C BY (C_ID);
E = FOREACH D {
sorted = order C by time desc;
GENERATE group,C.methodName AS Flow ;
};
F = GROUP E BY (Flow);
G = FOREACH F {
GENERATE group,COUNT(E) AS FlowKount ;
};
STORE G INTO '$output' USING PigStorage();
```

but i get error - using bag as key not supported

Data corresponding to E in above program -

```
c1 {(m1), (m2), (m3) }
c2 {(m1), (m2), (m3) }
c3 {(m2), (m1), (m3) }
c4 {(m1), (m2), (m3) }
c5 {(m2), (m1), (m3) }
```

I need the output as -

```
{(m1), (m2), (m3) } {(c1),(c2),(c4)} 3
{(m2), (m1), (m3) } {(c3),(c5)} 2
```

which is - methods , C_Ids and count

its kind of checking the duplicate flows having the same methods in the bag with different C_ID

Can someone guide how to achieve this?

Comment: Please post a sample of input data that you are using.

Comment: can you give us some dummy data?

Comment: **482be07c3b** {(bool User::c::m1() const),(bool User::ClassName::m2() const),(ulong User::ClassName::m3() const),(ulong User::ClassName::m4() const),(virtual void user_Verify::Requirements::m5(ulong)),(bool User::ClassName::m1() const),(bool User::ClassName::m3() const)}

**482be02c3b** {(bool User::c::m1() const),(bool User::ClassName::m2() const),(ulong User::ClassName::m3() const),(ulong User::ClassName::m4() const),(virtual void user_Verify::Requirements::m5(ulong)),(bool User::ClassName::m1() const),(bool User::ClassName::m3() const)}

Comment: Above is sample data ,
I need to group different tuples where the second field which is a bag and find the count...
that is I need to find all the tuples which have same bag contents